# Error code P074B on a 2013 Ford Focus (2L engine)?

Tags: ford, focus

How do I correct an error code P074B for a 2013 Ford Focus (2L engine)? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like this means unable to engage 3rd gear.  Could you please include details on any other symptoms (ie, do the RPM's sky-rocket before coming down after second gear?) and general facts about the car (ie, manual vs. automatic; mileage, etc.)